# What is meant by: "Client side asynchronous frameworks"

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I was looking at a job posting requesting a desired knowledge of: "Client side asynchronous frameworks".  What do they mean by this with respect to Microsoft technologies, specifically .NET framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it refers to AJAX technologies, like [ASP.NET Ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajax/) and [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax).

Answer (score 3):

That would be what is more commonly known as [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine anything (or at least one technology) that runs on the client side, and I would assume over the web: Ajax (jQuery, Prototype, ASP.NET AJAX, etc.), Silverlight, Flash, Java FX, etc..